# Git permission what's the difference between file permission and special ACLs

Tags: git, version-control

As mentioned in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine) or [here](https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_repository_access_control), defining user specific read/write access is to be done with using special extended ACLs.

However, the [git compendium](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) states that everything can be done with file permissions.

> "If a user SSHs into a server and has write access to the
>   /srv/git/my_project.git directory, they will also automatically have
>   push access."

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter *how* you control permission to the `.git` directory via normal unix file permissions or something more exotic like ACLs:  if a user has read permission to the `.git` directory, they can read (`git clone` or `git fetch`).  If a user has write permission, they can write to it (via a `git push`).

This is true of users who are fetching or cloning over SSH or over the local filesystem.  If you use some web server in front to serve repositories over HTTP(s), then it may add its own level of security.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but why does one of the pages say "For maximum control on repository level you can use extended ACLs [...]" (rephrased) - the author makes it look like there is something that you cannot do with simple permissions. But if the access rights define push/pull privileges on a repo level already, what's left?

Comment: @taclight I think the advantage in ACLs would be their inheritance.  You can configure fine grained permissions for the `.git` folder that are inherited by new files created beneath them, whereas with the standard unix permission model you have less flexibility when it comes to new files (basically, they will be created with the given `umask`).